# User input with multithreading Ruby

Tags: ruby, multithreading

I'm trying to make one thread display the current time while the user enters some input in the main thread.

When I run this,

```
thr=Thread.new {
  loop {
    time = Time.now
    puts time.strftime("Time: %H:%M:%S")
    sleep(1)
    print"\033[A","\033[K"
  }
}
thr.join
print"Name: ";name=gets.chomp
```

the time string moves too on the terminal, and it copies what I type in the main thread too.

Is there a way to lock a string or divide the threads?

Comment: what do you mean "string moves"? JFYI, your code never gets to `name=gets.chomp` part. Because your thread runs an infinite loop and you   wait for it to finish (which it never does).

Comment: @SergioTulentsev but I think it should be infinite if it has to keep counting the time till the main thread its done.. For example, if you run that, and u press the space key, the time string will be moved one character to the right too.. I need the time thread to keep counting the time while the main thread do his work..
Basically, I need to put a clock inside my program
Sorry for my english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, don't call `Thread#join`, because at that point your main thread blocks and will do nothing further until the `thr` thread exits, and it never will.

Second, the terminal doesn't know anything about threads.  You have to make your threads play nice with each other as far as cursor positioning.  The easiest way to do that is to have the one that is interrupting and seizing the cursor save the position and restore it when it has done its thing.

```
print "\033[2J" # clear screen
print "\033[4;2fName: " # absolute position for prompt

thr = Thread.new {
  loop {
    print "\0337" # save cursor position
    print "\033[2;2f\033[2K" # absolution position for clock
    print Time.now.strftime("Time: %H:%M:%S") 
    print "\0338" # restore cursor position
    sleep(1)
  }
}

name = gets.chomp
puts "Hello, #{name}."

sleep # forever, because thread 'thr' will be killed when the main program exits
```

Comment: thank you so much for your reply! That solved my problem!
Can i just aks you to explain me the absolute position for both prompt and clock? I refer to this link for an ASCII table, but i can't find anything about the absolute position:

http://ascii-table.com/ansi-escape-sequences-vt-100.php

Thanks again!

Comment: Google "vt100 escape sequences," I think you'll find it.  ESC+[{row};{column}f is the escape sequence for absolute positioning.

Comment: It's actually in the page you linked.  

Esc[Line;Columnf Move cursor to screen location v,h CUP